# Send SMS at a time interval without user interaction until i didn't stop

Tags: ios, sms

I want  in  my app that when i  click a button (start)  SMS would sent on saved contacts    in my app with a one click on alert window but using MFMessageComposeViewController i have to click on send then it sent then how can i send SMS without user interaction until stop button is not clicked.

Comment: I don't see any possible way to temper MFMessageComposeViewController For doing what you want, Better way is to use some SMS Gateway API Service.

Comment: thanks @ Rv15 .Can you plz suggest any API for it.

Answer (score 0):

here are some Paid SMS APIs , you just need to call their service on periodic basic(probably by calling a method which is called repeatedly using NSTimer) :

[www.world-text.com](http://www.world-text.com),
[www.gateway160.com](http://www.gateway160.com),
http://www.smsglobal.com/,
[www.nexmo.com](http://www.nexmo.com)

Or please check [this](http://blog.mashape.com/post/56272188360/list-of-50-sms-apis) link, it has list of 50+ SMS APIs